# Why doesn't FindBugs generate any reports?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, findbugs

I have a multimodule project and want to generate FindBugs report either for the entire code, or, at least, for every individual module (and then aggregate individual results with https://code.google.com/p/findbugs-aggregator/ ).

But when I run `mvn site`, neither individual report, nor the aggregated report is generated.

How can I fix this?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mycompany-studio</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.mycompany.parentproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.21.0</tycho-version>
        <tycho-extras-version>0.21.0</tycho-extras-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <antrun-version>1.7</antrun-version>
        <supermirror>file:///home/jenkins/repo/supermirror</supermirror>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Supermirror repository</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${supermirror}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
            <url>${project.baseUri}</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>'mycompany_'yyyyMMddHHmm</format>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module1</module>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module2</module>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module3</module>
    </modules>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7</version>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <configLocation>sun-coding-standard.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                                <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
                                <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                            </configuration>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <id>aggregate</id>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>aggregate</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

**Update 1 (25.09.2014 14:39):** New version, still doesn't work.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mycompany-studio</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.mycompany.parentproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.21.0</tycho-version>
        <tycho-extras-version>0.21.0</tycho-extras-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <antrun-version>1.7</antrun-version>
        <supermirror>file:///home/jenkins/repo/supermirror</supermirror>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Supermirror repository</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${supermirror}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
            <url>${project.baseUri}</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>'mycompany_'yyyyMMddHHmm</format>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module1</module>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module2</module>
        <module>../com.mycompany.module3</module>
    </modules>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7</version>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <configLocation>sun-coding-standard.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                                <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
                                <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                            </configuration>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <id>aggregate</id>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>aggregate</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5.5</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <xmlOutputDirectory>site</xmlOutputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

**Update 2 (25.09.2014):** End of the output of `mvn clean site`.

```
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:jaxen:jar:1.1.6 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:joda-time:jar:2.3.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:net.sf.oval:jar:1.83.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:net.sourceforge.lpg.lpgjavaruntime:jar:1.1.0
.v201004271650 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-antlr.jar:1.9.2.v
201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:1
.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:1.
9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:
1.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:1.
9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar
:1.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-resolver.j
ar:1.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar
:1.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-commons-logging.j
ar:1.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-commons-net.jar:1
.9.2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-jai.jar:1.9.2.v20
1404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-javamail.jar:1.9.
2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-jdepend.jar:1.9.2
.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-jmf.jar:1.9.2.v20
1404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-jsch.jar:1.9.2.v2
01404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-junit.jar:1.9.2.v
201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-junit4.jar:1.9.2.
v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-launcher.jar:1.9.
2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-netrexx.jar:1.9.2
.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-swing.jar:1.9.2.v
201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant-testutil.jar:1.9.
2.v201404171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.ant:jar:lib/ant.jar:1.9.2.v201404
171502 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.batik.css:jar:1.7.0.v201011041433
 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.batik.util:jar:1.7.0.v20101104143
3 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.batik.util.gui:jar:1.7.0.v2009030
91627 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.compress:jar:1.6.0.v20131
0281400 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.2.0.v20140521120
0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.apache.commons.lang3:jar:3.1.0.v20140328
1430 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.cxx:jar:3.2.0.201
406111759 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui:jar:3.2.0.201406111
759 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui.cxx:jar:3.2.0.20140
6111759 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.cdt.core.lrparser:jar:5.2.0.2014
06111759 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.cdt.core.native:jar:5.7.0.201406
111759 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.compare:jar:3.5.500.v20131106-15
52 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.compare.core:jar:3.5.400.v201309
03-0736 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.commands:jar:3.6.100.v20140
528-1422 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.contenttype:jar:3.4.200.v20
140207-1251 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.databinding:jar:1.4.1.v2014
0214-0004 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable:jar:
1.4.1.v20140210-1835 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.databinding.property:jar:1.
4.200.v20140214-0004 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.expressions:jar:3.4.600.v20
140128-0851 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.filebuffers:jar:3.5.400.v20
140127-1516 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.filesystem:jar:1.4.100.v201
40514-1614 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.jobs:jar:3.6.0.v20140424-00
53 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.resources:jar:3.9.0.v201405
14-1307 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.runtime:jar:3.10.0.v2014031
8-2214 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.core.variables:jar:3.2.800.v2013
0819-1716 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.debug.core:jar:3.9.0.v20140521-1
435 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.debug.ui:jar:3.10.0.v20140604-16
37 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.core.commands:jar:0.10.2.v201
40424-2344 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts:jar:1.3.100.v20
140407-1019 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.core.di:jar:1.4.0.v20140414-1
837 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions:jar:0.12.0
.v20140417-2033 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.core.services:jar:1.2.0.v2014
0509-1840 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings:jar:0.10.200.v201
40424-2042 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core:jar:0.10.100.v201
40424-2042 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt:jar:0.11.100.v2014
0522-1045 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme:jar:0.9.300.
v20140424-2042 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.di:jar:1.0.0.v20140328-211
2 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench:jar:1.1.0.
v20140512-1820 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.services:jar:1.1.0.v201403
28-1925 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets:jar:1.0.0.v2014051
4-1823 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench:jar:1.1.0.v20140
528-1949 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt:jar:1
.1.0.v20140602-1537 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt:ja
r:0.12.0.v20140521-1818 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt:jar:0.12.100
.v20140530-1436 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3:jar:0.12.0.v201
40227-2118 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.egit.core:jar:3.4.0.201406110918
-r has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.emf.common:jar:2.10.0.v20140514-
1158 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.emf.ecore:jar:2.10.0.v20140514-1
158 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change:jar:2.10.0.v201
40514-1158 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi:jar:2.10.0.v201405
14-1158 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.app:jar:1.3.200.v2013091
0-1609 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.bidi:jar:0.10.0.v2013032
7-1442 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.common:jar:3.6.200.v2013
0402-1505 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.ds:jar:1.4.200.v20131126
-2331 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core:jar:2.3.0.v20131
211-1531 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine:jar:2.3.0.v201
40506-1720 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata:jar:2.2.0.v2
0131211-1531 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository:j
ar:1.2.100.v20131209-2144 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository:jar:2.3.0.
v20131211-1531 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences:jar:3.5.200.
v20140224-1527 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.registry:jar:3.5.400.v20
140428-1507 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.security:jar:1.2.0.v2013
0424-1801 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.util:jar:1.0.500.v201304
04-1337 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.help:jar:3.6.0.v20130326-1254 ha
s no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.jface:jar:3.10.0.v20140604-0740
has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.jface.databinding:jar:1.6.200.v2
0140528-1422 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.jface.text:jar:3.9.0.v20140521-1
657 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:3.4.0.201406110918-r ha
s no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring:jar:3.6.100
.v20140520-1248 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring:jar:3.7.100.v
20140324-1358 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.10.0.v20140606-1445 h
as no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.osgi.services:jar:3.4.0.v2014031
2-2051 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.search:jar:3.9.100.v20140226-163
7 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.swt:jar:3.103.0.v20140605-2008 h
as no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86:jar:3.103.0.v2
0140605-2012 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:jar:3.103.0
.v20140605-2012 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86:jar:3.103.0.
v20140605-2012 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:jar:3.103
.0.v20140605-2012 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.team.core:jar:3.7.0.v20130514-12
24 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.team.ui:jar:3.7.100.v20130710-12
13 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.text:jar:3.5.300.v20130515-1451
has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui:jar:3.106.0.v20140519-0906 ha
s no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.console:jar:3.5.300.v20140424
-1437 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.editors:jar:3.8.200.v20140401
-1310 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.forms:jar:3.6.100.v20140422-1
825 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.ide:jar:3.10.0.v20140521-1937
 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.navigator:jar:3.5.400.v201402
10-1835 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources:jar:3.4.7
00.v20140407-1004 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.views:jar:3.7.0.v20140408-070
3 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed:jar:3
.6.0.v20140519-0906 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.workbench:jar:3.106.0.v201405
30-0732 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor:jar:3.9.
0.v20140411-1521 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.glassfish.jersey.all:jar:2.5.1 has no fi
le.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.jgrapht:jar:0.9.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.simpleframework:jar:2.7.0.201408211224 h
as no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.slf4j.api:jar:1.7.2.v20121108-1250 has n
o file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.w3c.css.sac:jar:1.3.1.v200903091627 has
no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.w3c.dom.events:jar:3.0.0.draft20060413_v
201105210656 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.w3c.dom.smil:jar:1.0.1.v200903091627 has
 no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: p2.eclipse-plugin:org.w3c.dom.svg:jar:1.1.0.v201011041433 has
no file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] com.mycompany.parent ................................. SUCCESS [ 35.571 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.module1 .............................. SUCCESS [  2.162 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.module2 ........................ SUCCESS [  6.987 s]
...
[INFO] com.mycompany.moduleN ........................... SUCCESS [  0.820 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:56 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-25T12:34:49+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 183M/1692M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update 3 (25.09.2014 14:59 MSK):** New pom.xml.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    mycompany-studio
    com.mycompany.parentproject
    1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    pom

```
<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.21.0</tycho-version>
    <tycho-extras-version>0.21.0</tycho-extras-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <antrun-version>1.7</antrun-version>
    <supermirror>file:///home/jenkins/repo/supermirror</supermirror>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Supermirror repository</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>${supermirror}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Codehaus repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
        <url>${project.baseUri}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <format>'mycompany_'yyyyMMddHHmm</format>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>../com.mycompany.module1</module>
    <module>../com.mycompany.module2</module>
    <module>../com.mycompany.module3</module>
</modules>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>sun-coding-standard.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
                            <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                        </configuration>
                        <reportSets>
                            <reportSet>
                                <id>aggregate</id>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>aggregate</report>
                                </reports>
                            </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <!-- Optional directory to put findbugs xdoc xml report -->
                <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2.5.5 version of findbugs plugin and specify xmlOutputDirectory param in findbug configuration

Comment: Thanks. See my update 1. I tried, what you recommended, but it doesn't work. Are there any obvious errors in my pom.xml?

Comment: What is the output in console when you run maven?

Comment: Did you try changing the path of plugin to reporting/plugins and not reporting/plugins/plugin/configuration/reportPlugins

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mycompany-studio</groupId>
<artifactId>com.mycompany.parentproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.21.0</tycho-version>
    <tycho-extras-version>0.21.0</tycho-extras-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <antrun-version>1.7</antrun-version>
    <supermirror>file:///home/jenkins/repo/supermirror</supermirror>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Supermirror repository</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>${supermirror}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>${project.artifactId}-site</id>
        <url>${project.baseUri}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <format>'mycompany_'yyyyMMddHHmm</format>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>sun-coding-standard.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
                            <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                        </configuration>
                        <reportSets>
                            <reportSet>
                                <id>aggregate</id>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>aggregate</report>
                                </reports>
                            </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
             <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```